# Как с помощью SQL запроса найти, какая строка была удалена?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Есть таблица, состоящая из 1 столбца `Client` и 100 строк. В этом столбце, неповторяющиеся числа от 1 до 100.

Из таблицы произвольным образом была удалена 1 строка.

Как с помощью SQL запроса определить, какая строка была удалена?

Comment: Приведите пример своего решения, и мы подскажем, в чем ваша ошибка и как ее устранить. Так же, обращу внимание, что данный ресурс является ресурсом для ответов на вопросы, 
а не площадкой по решению заданий. 
Хотите, что бы кто-то за вас сделал вашу работу - 
обращайтесь к фрилансерам.

Comment: @cauf если бы у автора были идеи, тогда и вопрос бы не понадобилось задавать. Работы тут тоже нет, вопрос достаточно узкий и потенциально имеющий практическую полезность. Предъявы глупые.

Comment: @andreymal чушь поришь. Если нет идей - надо гуглить и курить доки,а не сразу бежать постить вопросы. По крайней мере на первой странице выдачи поиска есть пара ссылок, которые могут навести на идеи

Comment: @cauf тогда Stack Overflow нужно закрывать, так как 99% ответов на вопросы можно самостоятельно найти в документации. Вы тоже должны удалить все свои 7 вопросов, так как все они решаются вдумчивым чтением документации.

Comment: @cauf  _на первой странице выдачи поиска есть пара ссылок_, совершенно верно, и с сегодняшнего дня самая первая ссылка ведёт на эту тему. Вопрос достаточно узко поставлен, и если бы ТС нагуглил бы идею, то он бы задачу решил (где тут можно ошибится?). Трудно представить, что задача в вопросе навеяна законченным бизнес требованием, а предложенные ответы являются его полными решениями. Так что, о "выполненой за кого-то работе" тут говорить не совсем уместно. Это только идеи, пути решения. И самое главное, как уже заметил выше, теперь эти идеи гуглятся у нас, а не на хабре или sql.ru.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
create table t1 as
    select rownum id from xmlTable ('1 to 100')
/
```

Удалим одну случайную запись:

```
delete from t1 where id = (
    select trunc (dbms_random.value (1,100)) from dual)

1 row deleted.
```

Найдём, что удалили:

```
select rn missing from (
    select row_number () over (order by id) rn, id from t1)
where rn != id order by id fetch first row only 
/
   MISSING
----------
        24
```

---

Из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1156268/sql-%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8#comment2005311_1156291):

> К примеру если записей не от 1 до 100 а до 1000000, быстро ли отработает запрос

Не знаю. Смотрите планы выполнения на реальных данных. Следующий запрос может будет быстрей, и к тому же, найдёт все "дырки", запрос выше только первую:

```
select  id + 1 missing
from t1 
where not exists (
    select  null
    from t1 t2
    where  t2.id = t1.id + 1)
and id != 100    
/
```

Answer (score 2):

Достаточно очевидно, что неповторяющиеся числа  от 1 до 100 - это арифметическая прогрессия. Посчитайте ее сумму, и потом SELECT (sum_of_progression - SUM(number)) AS answer FROM your_table

Comment: Что такое? Как прогрессия спасет.тну вот вы получили число 10 и что?

Comment: ты можешь быстро посчитать сумму чисел от 1 до 100 по формуле суммы прогрессии. в таблице одного числа не хватает. считаем сумму без одного числа. вычитаем первое из второго, получаем искомое число. получили число 10, значит удалена 10-я строка

Comment: С какого перепуга не хватает только одного числа?

Comment: Ну так прочитайте условие задачи.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так.
Вам нужно сгенерировать саму последовательность 1..100 и соединить через left нужную таблицу.

```
WITH InfiniteRows (RowNumber) AS (

  SELECT 1 AS RowNumber
  UNION ALL

  SELECT a.RowNumber + 1    AS 
   RowNumber
  FROM   InfiniteRows a
  WHERE  a.RowNumber < 100
)
SELECT RowNumber
FROM   InfiniteRows
LEFT JOIN Client
ON InfiniteRows.RowNumber = Client.Id
WHERE client.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: А есть другие варианты? К примеру если записей не от 1 до 100 а до 1000000, быстро ли отработает запрос

Comment: Вариантов масса но идея та же. У вас должны быть все номера и с помощью них выбирать не хватающие

Comment: WITH InfiniteRows  AS (
Select Rownum as RowNumber  
From dual
Connect By Rownum <= 100
)
SELECT RowNumber
FROM   InfiniteRows
LEFT JOIN Client
ON InfiniteRows.RowNumber = Client.Id
WHERE client.id IS NULL;

Comment: В любом случае нужно чтобы были эти id по левую сторону. Чтобы не было запроса типа А на ком вы не женаты